# fetching and updating data from web service

Tags: asp.net

Data can be fetched into an application through web service can it be possible to update data in web service from our application ..

Answer (score 0):

Of course create a web method that takes parameters and then save the data as required

```
[WebMethod]
public bool UpdateData(string firstName, string lastName, int id)
{
    // do some data access code here
}
```

Then use in your code in a similar way as to when your are acquiring data from the web service:

```
MyWebServiceClient client = new MyWebServiceClient();
bool updated = client.UpdateData("Jon", "Skeet", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general a Web Service implementation can be any arbitrary code, so insert/update/delete is nothing special.

I suspect that there's something behind your question, some specific issue in mind? You may want to explain why you think there's a problem.